# Concat list null check

Tags: c#, linq

I have five variables in which they have individual data, after that i am concatenating their respective charge volumes to one variable. This works fine.

Now the issue is suppose that I have only one data (`var CCPcv` has data) and the rest do not have data, `var CombinedPcv` line breaks because the charge volume is null for other variables. There can be n number of scenarios (2 have data, 3 have data etc).

One approach is that I check each individual variable for a null value and then do a null check on a combination of variables.

Please suggest a better approach.

```
var CCPcv = (GuidedPcvYear1CCViewModel)wizard.Steps[est bettgwizard.OrderedSteps[typeof(GuidedPcvYear1CCViewModel)]];
var CPCPcv = (GuidedPcvYear1CPCViewModel)wizard.Steps[wizard.OrderedSteps[typeof(GuidedPcvYear1CPCViewModel)]];
var VpayPcv = (GuidedPcvYear1VPAViewModel)wizard.Steps[wizard.OrderedSteps[typeof(GuidedPcvYear1VPAViewModel)]];
var BIPPcv = (GuidedPcvYear1BIPViewModel)wizard.Steps[wizard.OrderedSteps[typeof(GuidedPcvYear1BIPViewModel)]];
var GnicsCCPcv = (GuidedPcvYear1CCGnicsViewModel)wizard.Steps[wizard.OrderedSteps[typeof(GuidedPcvYear1CCGnicsViewModel)]];

var CombinedCV = CCPcv.ChargeVolumes.ConvertAll(cv=>cv).Concat(CPCPcv.ChargeVolumes.ConvertAll(x=>x).Concat(VpayPcv.ChargeVolumes.ConvertAll(z=>z).Concat(BIPPcv.ChargeVolumes.ConvertAll(a=>a).Concat(GnicsCCPcv.ChargeVolumes.ConvertAll(s=>s)))));
year1ChargeVolumes = CombinedCV.ToList();
```

Comment: You could write your own *extension method* to do the null check and *Concat* and reuse that for all of your variables/collections

Comment: Can you give example in above case ?

Comment: What's with all the `ConvertAll`s and nested `Concat`s? Just make sure your enumerables are never null and concat one after another.

Comment: @user662285, Gave you an example below in he answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a helper method like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatTreatingNullsAsEmpty<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sequences)
{
    return 
        from sequence in sequences where sequence != null
        from item in sequence
        select item;
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
IEnumerable<int> seq1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
IEnumerable<int> seq2 = null;
IEnumerable<int> seq3 = Enumerable.Range(6, 5);
IEnumerable<int> seq4 = null;
IEnumerable<int> seq5 = Enumerable.Range(11, 5);

var numbers = ConcatTreatingNullsAsEmpty(seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4, seq5);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers)); // Prints 1, 2, ..., 14, 15
```

I think your code would then look like this:

```
var CombinedCV = ConcatTreatingNullsAsEmpty(
    CCPcv      .ChargeVolumes, 
    CPCPcv     .ChargeVolumes,
    VpayPcv    .ChargeVolumes,
    BIPPcv     .ChargeVolumes,
    GnicsCCPcv .ChargeVolumes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the extension method:

```
static class MyConcatExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ConcatNotNulls<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection1, IEnumerable<T> collection2)
    {
        // collection is null, you might want to check collection1 as well
        if (collection2 == null)
        {
            return collection1;
        }

        // collection of reference types has null items 
        if (!typeof(T).IsValueType)
        {
            return collection1.Concat(collection2.Where(item => item != null));

        }

        // collection of value types
        return collection1.Concat(collection2);
    }
}
```

And you could use it like:

```
list1.ConcatNotNulls(list2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one approach is to ensure you never have `null` enumerables - use `Enumerable.Empty` instead of `null` whenever you need an empty enumerable.

If this is not viable, you can make a simple extension method to convert a `null` enumerable to an empty enumerable:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this T @this)
   => Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

Also, there's no need to nest the `Concat`s. You can do something like this instead:

```
var combined =
  CCPcv?.ChargeVolumes?.NotNull()
  .Concat(CPCPcv?.ChargeVolumes?.NotNull())
  .Concat(VpayPcv?.ChargeVolumes?.NotNull())
  .Concat(BIPPcv?.ChargeVolumes?.NotNull())
  .Concat(GnicsCCPcv?.ChargeVolumes?.NotNull());
```

Finally, it sounds like your objects should really share a common interface. If that's the case, you can write another helper method that applies the same operation on multiple enumerables:

```
public static IEnumerable<ICV> DoStuff(params ICV[] cvs)
  => cvs.SelectMany(i => i?.ChargeVolumes?.NotNull());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
        var tempList = new List<GuidedPcvYear1CCViewModel>() { CCPcv ,CPCPcv,VpayPcv,BIPPcv,GnicsCCPcv};
        var CombinedCv = tempList.Where(i => i != null).ToList();
```

You just have to convert them before adding to list.